# SilverStripe page create error Class 'DateField' not found

Tags: php, silverstripe

Im creating new SilverStripe project based on the [tutorial](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/tutorials/extending_a_basic_site/) of SilverStripe.

After adding this code, the CMS field dont show and gives error.

```
class ArticlePage extends Page {
private static $db = array(
    'Date' => 'Date',
    'Author' => 'Text',
);

// .....

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $dateField = new DateField('Date', 'Article Date (for example: 20/12/2010)');
    $dateField->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
    $dateField->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd/MM/YYYY');

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $dateField, 'Content');
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Author', 'Author Name'), 'Content');

    return $fields;
}
```

}

the error is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DateField' not found in sample/sample/ line*
```

I don't see any problem with the code as I copy it from the tutorial itself. please help

Comment: Does your file have a namespace? Also, are you following SilverStripe 3 tutorials but in a SilverStripe 4 project? Can you share the contents of `composer show` in your terminal?

Comment: either v3 and v4 gives the same error.

Comment: i mean both of them, no matter what code I copy gives the same error

Comment: 4 would require a namespace, 3 should work. Can you provide more code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: can you please explain about the namespace. im just new with  the framework

Answer (score 0):

Insert this at the top of *`ArticlePage.php`*:

```
use SilverStripe\Forms\DateField;
```